# How to know which field in Data base changed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing a Travel Operator Management System that manage all the services and tours of a company. And i need to know which fields changed when a user update their database.
For ex:
I have a table name service with columns:
Service name
Date Start
Date End
Itinerary

An user update a service that change the Date Start from 05/25/2015 to 05/27/2015 so i need to tracking this, i must notification for user who work on this rows that this service has changed Date Start from 05/25/2015 to 05/27/2015. How can i do with ASP MVC 4 or 5?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sql notification for this, Also you can use some backgroud service that continue look in queue table and the queue gets data form on update trigger of sql.

Comment: You mean i should use SQL notification then use ASP MVC to get it data?

Comment: I knows  Two way 1. Sql notication
               2. Trigger , queue table, read data

Comment: Thank you!!! Anybody has other method that use only ASP MVC? I am not profession with SQL Server

Comment: Then you can choose second way:
you simply need one update trigger that fires and insert information to once queue (any) table and you can read from you action after some specif time interval or event